# Can't add any email connection on macOS Mojave

Tags: mail.app, email, accounts, imap

I am not able to add a new internet account/email account to my Mac.

After entering all required information, I am just seeing an infinity loop. No timeout - nothing.

[image]

This happens with new accounts and already existing ones. Also, I don't see any attempt for a connect on the mailserver (I am the admin there as well).

Tried deleting all information from the keychain. No luck.

Also using Thunderbird didn't work. I have tried rebooting the router, a wifi hotspot on the iPhone (different ISP), different dns entry for the mailserver (to avoid certificate clash), hosts entry and disabling the firewall. 
A telnet connection to the according ports works fine.

Also tried adding the account on a different Mac, which worked perfectly fine.

Any suggestion is more then welcome.